# How to create a WaterDrop Shape with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, shapes, uibezierpath

I write some code for creating the below with UIBezierPath but it didn't work. Can someone help me what's wrong with my code.

but i was tried with drawRect: it works fine....My problem is same i need in UIBezierPath as,

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)DropShape:(CGRect)Frame {}
```

my code using drawRect: is

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGGradientRef gradient;
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace;
CGFloat locations[3] = { 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 };

NSArray *colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor];

colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace,
                                      (CFArrayRef)colors, locations);

CGPoint startPoint, endPoint;
CGFloat startRadius, endRadius;

startPoint.x = self.frame.size.width/2;
startPoint.y = 30;
endPoint.x = 175;
endPoint.y = 175;
startRadius = 0;
endRadius = 75;

CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, startPoint,
                            startRadius, endPoint, endRadius, 0);
```

Thanks in advance...[image: Screen]

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with the `xcode` IDE so I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app called [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) which you can try for free.

You can draw onto a canvas and it will produce the `drawRect` code that you can copy and paste into your app.

I don't think you can copy from the trial version but it will create the path which you can type into your code manually.

It's worth a look.